# Combine two subs with changing ranges

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I want to combine these two lines of code but cannot figure out how to get it to work.  They both work separately, but I want the first line of code to be the first operation and then the second sub to be the second operation.  These should execute whenever there is a change to the worksheet.  The first routine should only cause a msg box when the corresponding cell in the "S" range updates in the same row as the cell that was updated in column A or B.

The second operation should look for any change in range "T7:T26" and prompt a msg box.

Code is below:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim myRng As Range
Dim lRow As Long

If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

On Error GoTo Whoa

Set myRng = Range("A7:B26")

Application.EnableEvents = False

If Not Intersect(Target, myRng) Is Nothing Then
    lRow = Target.Row

    If Range("S" & lRow).Value >= 16 Then sVar = _
    MsgBox("Will Enough Pre-Wave Resources be Available?", 4, "Attention!")

    If sVar = 7 Then Application.Undo
End If

    Letscontinue:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
    Whoa:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Letscontinue


    End Sub
```

and

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim myRng As Range

    Set myRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SMT 5").Range("T7:T26")

        For Each mycell In myRng

    If mycell.Value = "ISSUE" Then sVar = MsgBox("Possible Pre-Wave Manpower Issue on     2nd or 3rd Shift. Will Enough Resources be Available?", 4, "Attention!")

If sVar = 7 Then

Application.Undo

End If

Exit For

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Based on your previous question.. are the values coming in Col T from a formula?

Comment: Yes they are.  So anytime a cell in the range "T7:T26" changes I want the msg box from the second sub to appear.  The cells in the this range can change based on any input in the range "A1:B26", even if the cell does not intersect.

Comment: can you show me the formula that is populating `T`?

Comment: =IF(AND(M7>=$S$1,M7<=$S$2,S7>10),"ISSUE",IF(AND(M7>=$T$1,M7<=$T$2,S7>4),"ISSUE",""))

Comment: are you sure this is the formula? Don't see any cell from `A1:B26` in the formula

Comment: Positive.  But this formula points to column S which works off of Column M, which works off the inputs of a couple other columns.  Column A is where we put the sub-assembly name and through multiple vlookups the other columns populate which feed the columns that fees column S and T.

Comment: so what if there are multiple "ISSUE" in Col T? Are you ok to get multiple messages?

Comment: Check the code that I posted. Is that what you are trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim myRng As Range
Dim lRow As Long

If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

On Error GoTo Whoa

Set myRng = Range("A7:B26")

Application.EnableEvents = False

If Not Intersect(Target, myRng) Is Nothing Then
    lRow = Target.Row

    If Range("S" & lRow).Value >= 16 Then sVar = _
    MsgBox("Will Enough Pre-Wave Resources be Available?", 4, "Attention!")

    If sVar = 7 Then Application.Undo
End If

Set othrRng = Range("T7:T26")

For Each aCell In othrRng

    If aCell.Value = "ISSUE" Then sVar = MsgBox("Possible Pre-Wave Manpower Issue on 2nd or 3rd Shift. Will Enough Resources be Available?", 4, "Attention!")

    If sVar = 7 Then

    Application.Undo
    Exit For

End If

Next

Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub

Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue

End Sub
```

Comment: If you have a different answer then do post it but do not post the same answer that I posted. :) If you wish, you can accept the relevant answer by clicking the Green Check Mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If both of them work on their own, you can copy the code into a module and give them two distinct names.
Then, in the Worksheet_Change sub you just use `Call` to run both subs.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Const sMsg1 As String = "Will Enough Pre-Wave Resources be Available?"

Const sMsg2 As String = "Possible Pre-Wave Manpower Issue on " & _
"2nd or 3rd Shift. Will Enough Resources be Available?"

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim myRng As Range, othrRng As Range, aCell As Range
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim sVar

    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Set myRng = Range("A7:A26")
    Set othrRng = Range("T7:T26")

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, myRng) Is Nothing Then
        lRow = Target.Row

        If Range("S" & lRow).Value >= 16 Then sVar = _
        MsgBox(sMsg1, 4, "Attention!")

        If sVar = 7 Then Application.Undo
    End If

    For Each aCell In othrRng
        If aCell.Value = "ISSUE" Then _
        sVar = MsgBox(sMsg2, 4, "Attention!")

        If sVar = 7 Then
            Application.Undo
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

Comment: This did what I needed: